# How to cache images in UITableView without external Libraries?

Tags: ios, uitableview, url, uiimageview

Iam trying to cache images without using external libraries in UITableview.
But i didnt get any results for that. My images are loading from URL .i have more than 40 images and is there any way to cache rather than loading directly ??

am using following code for loading image form URL

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"cell";

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[testingTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier]
        ;
    }


    dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{
        data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            cell.img.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        });
    });

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I realize you don't want an external library, but why? I agree with you that most don't give great results, and still experience missing images or flickering. That's why I wrote UIImageLoader. It gives you much more control, is only two files so it's super simple to add into xcode. And there's a great sample in the repo. https://github.com/gngrwzrd/UIImageLoader

Answer (score 2):

You can use [NSCache](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html), NSCache works like an NSMutableDictionary with the advantage that is thread safe, with also some auto removal policies
 
Depending on your requirements you can create a singleton instance of it:

```
@interface SharedCache : NSCache
+ (id)sharedInstance;

@end

@implementation SharedCache

- (void) emptyCache{
    [self removeAllObjects];
}


-(void) dealloc{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self];
}

-(id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(emptyCache) name:UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification object:[UIApplication sharedApplication]];
    }
    return self;
}

+(id)sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t pred = 0;
    __strong static id _sharedObject = nil;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        _sharedObject = [[self alloc] init]; 
    });
    return _sharedObject;
}

@end
```

Of course you should take care about check whether or not the image is already cached with a specified key.

Comment: can u please tell me how to use this on my case?

Comment: After you successfully download an image you add it to the cache using as key the url of the image. When you need the image you ask the cache if there is an image for that key, if not you download it, if there is you display it.

Comment: dop u have any example project or sample copy of codes..becoz am new to this

Answer (score -1):

Why wouldn't you use libraries? A very good one to use is UIImageView+AFNetworking from [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) UIKit which loads an Image from a URL asynchronously and also caches your images.

example code:

```
[yourImageView setImageWithURL:youURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Comment: If you didnt read my question please do it first boss. I dont want any external libraries.